# Setting the height and width of a background color behind a form element

Tags: html, css

On the following web page:

http://www.hiv.lanl.gov/content/sequence/GENE_CUTTER/cutter.html

...you'll notice that there are three "input areas" each of which has a grey box behind it. I realize this is a simple question, but how was this effect achieved? I'm writing a similar application and I find the contrasting colors aesthetically appealing.

Thanks.

Caitlin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the code of the webpage by viewing its **source code** or rightclicking and choosing "Explore object" or something like that, you will see that they have the inputs in table and table with `class="paramtable"` which has a `background-color: rgb(227, 227, 227);` which is some kind of gray as long as the red, green and blue numbers are same.

So don't wait for using nice styles when writing your website :)

Answer (score 1):

What they most likely did what create classes for the items that are within the form element, and then in their .css file, they set the background color to the light gray color. You can see more about all this here: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com)